# Is there any GitHub template (example application) for Calling azure ad graph API in an .net web API project, not .net web application?

Tags: github, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create a secured .Net web API application that is used to call Azure Ad Graph API's crud operations. I don't see any sample applications in GitHub? Is there any such example available anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) that demonstrate the *On-Behalf-Of* flow - which can be used to call any downstream Web API, including Microsoft Graph.

More information about the *On Behalf Of* flow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i wanted and it helped me in understanding concept and implementing onto my application.